Relation Does not Exist Error While Using Existing database with Rails new Project
I already done one project using Rails 6 version with PostgreSQL 9.6 version. And for learning TDD purpose, I created new project and tried to use my old project's database. And I have Categories and Articles which are having many to many association. While I trying to run one simple test case it showing Relation categories does not exist error.
The same test model I copied to my old rails project, But there its successfully running.
I am new to Ruby and rails world. Is there any additional thing that I need to take care when using existing database to new project? Or Do I need to add the association again in my new project?
Can anyone suggest/guide me to avoid these type of errors while using existing database while working with new rails project please?

Don't make it harder on yourself. Start fresh with a new database. It will be much easier to focus on learning the TDD concepts if you start with a clean slate instead of a bunch of legacy.

Did you ensure your new config/database.yml file is pointing at the correct database? Your error sounds more on the Rails side than the Postgres side though. Can you add your test code?
